# Jquery toggle list read more/less button

Tags: jquery, list, toggle

I use now this script which works well, but i want also a read less button.
This i can't figure out how to do this. Hope somebody can help me with this.

```
$('#info')
      .find('tr:gt(5)')
      .hide()
      .end()
      .append(
            $('<tr><td class="show_more_btn">Read more &raquo;</tr></td>').click( function(){
              $(this).siblings(':hidden').show().end().remove();
    })
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your current javascript with:

```
$('#info').find('tr:gt(5)').addClass('toggletr').hide()
.end().append(
  $('<tr><td class="show_more_btn">Read more »</td></tr>').click(function(){
      $(this).siblings('.toggletr').toggle();
      if($(this).hasClass('expanded')){
          $(this).text('Read more »');
          $(this).removeClass('expanded');
      } else{
          $(this).text('Read less «');
          $(this).addClass('expanded');
      }
 })
);
```

You can get a smoother feel by replacing `.toggle()` with `.slideToggle()`, or `.fadeToggle()`.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this, because i get the button but no toggle between them.

Comment: Sure, I've edited to include a working implementation. You could probably make it a bit more elegant.

Comment: Thank you Allen, i get the idea but not that i would got this to work by myself so fast. But i think there is a little mistake in it because it doesn't look to work.

Here i made a example http://jsfiddle.net/eddyfever/wN4Lq/

Comment: Huh. I don't have access to debugging tools at the moment, but it worked when I was developing it in jsfiddle. Do you need to import jQuery?

Comment: This is already done, and i tried it in the header or at the end of the page. Does my jsfiddle work for you?

Comment: Oh, there was an extra `});` at the end. I don't know how it got there.